# How does state information get transferred when predicting with LSTM

Tags: deep-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I have a typical mutivariate time series forecasting problem that I want to solve using an LSTM, with mutliple features in the input sequnce and one feature in the output sequence. If I train my LSTM as follows:

```
# 1) Define
model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), 
stateful=True))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# 2) Train
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0,
 shuffle=False)

# 3) Predict
yhat = model.predict(X, batch_size=batch_size)
```

I understand that it is important to maintain the state during training, because I have a continuous sequence that has been broken up and lagged, which is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681046/keras-stateful-vs-stateless-lstms). This conceptually makes sense to me because during the training process the LSTM retains information on the entire training history, but this leads to my question:

In predict (part 3) of the code, when providing the network with a new unseen future sequence say sequence $X_{T+1}$, the model makes a prediction for that individual sequence. Now when providing the model with the next unseen future sequence $X_{T+2}$, how does it retain state over what happened in sequence $X_{T+1}$? Conceptually, I can undertstand if the model is retrained after every new unseen sequence, but is this the only way? Or is there some parameter in the `predict` function that I'm missing, or some custom walk forward approach?

**NOTE:**

- I'm using a batch size of 1
- I'm actually developing the model in R, but I've realised support for deep learning in R is near non-existant when compared to python so have written pseudo-like code which I'm not 100% confident about (code isn't the issue here)

.

Comment: The LSTM has 2 hidden states (cell and output) to track the next sequence.  If you don't reset the states, they retain the recurrent information.  Typically, during inference, you reset between sequences so that the states applies to the current sequence.  Predict will reset that for you, unless you use the flag 'stateful=True' in the creating of the LSTM.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thank you. Just to make sure when making one prediction (taking that 'stateful=True' during creation) by using model.predict(X_(T+1),batchsize=1) does the model actually update itself in the sense that the cell memory and next hidden state values (for that specific predict() call) are transferred to the the next predict call when doing model.predict(X_(T+2),batchsize=1). I would really appreciate the advice

Comment: Or if I'm planning on say making 10 predictions do I compile them all into a batch and then use the model.predict(X,batchsize=10). I really understand how the information flows in LSTM's, I'm just unsure about this predict function.

Comment: Typically, you only use stateful=True when you want to train longer sequences (although there are other uses), but then you need to take care during training.  If stateful=False, which would be typical for classification (many-to-one), you can just call predict and it will reset for you.  You can pass in a batch yes, but they will all be independent in terms of state.  That is my understanding.  IF stateful=True, then the NEXT batch you pass in would retain the corresponding state from the previous batch, with sequences respective.

Comment: Ok great, thank you. And yes my sequences are relatively long. With regards to being careful during training, I was planning on putting the model.fit in a loop where the fit function will have epochs=1 with a model.reset_states call directly after. Then the loop will run for say 50 epochs, which equates to traditional training except I make sure those states are reset to prevent any consequences from the stateful=True.